# Conditional data field firebase cloud function

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to add a conditional field to the data field of an fcm notification object in firebase cloud functions. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
const message = <admin.messaging.Message>{
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
      },
      android: {
        priority: "high",
      },
      data: {
        "type": notificationType,
        ...notificationType == notificationTypes.liveRoomAccepted &&
        {"liveroom-id": liveroomId},
      },
      apns: {
        headers: {
          "apns-priority": "10",
        },
        payload: {
          aps: {
            "contentAvailable": true,
          },
        },
      },
      token: token,
    };
```

But I keep getting an error like so: FirebaseMessagingError: data must only contain string values.

I also try printing the message object and the data field only has the "type" field. What is the right syntax for this please?

Comment: Does `…(notificationType == notificationTypes.liveRoomAccepted ? {"liveroom-id": liveroomId} : {})` work?

Comment: it does not work @lesiak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this code doesn't evaluate to a string value:

```
...notificationType == notificationTypes.liveRoomAccepted &&
        {"liveroom-id": liveroomId}
```

It sounds like you want to add an extra property to `data` for a certain notification type. The simplest way to do so that I can think of is:

```
data: (notificationType == notificationTypes.liveRoomAccepted) 
? {
    "type": notificationType,
    "liveroom-id": liveroomId,
  }
: {
    "type": notificationType,
  }
```

So we have a ternary expression here for the type check and then two separate objects: one for each outcome.